# bootstrap table-striped style on a table with missing cells

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap to display tables. Bootstrap's striped style is not applying on rows that have missing cells. This looks odd. How can I fix this ?
[image]

Comment: We can't possibly know how to fix your code unless you *showcase* it in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You're not new here - you know this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the only way is to add the missing cells, or add a `colspan = < nb missing cols +1>` to the last `<td>` on rows where there are missing cols...

According your code and the way your table is generated, you have several ways :

- add the missing columns while generating the table, so before the display
- add the missing cells after the table generation, with jquery code looping on each TR, counting the number of cells TD, and adding the missing ones with jquery after() function for example.